# Slow Azure Database Connection

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure

I'm moving from a Rackspace Cloud platform to Azure but I'm having some real performance issues. It seems like everything is a little but slower but especially database interaction.

I've done some load testing with all the different Scale options for both the CPU and the Sql Database and they only get comparable to the Rackspace account when they're all maxed out which seems excessive. Let me clarify, the Azure system can probably handle more load with it's higher scale options but it's reaction time for one user is slower than Rackspace.  I didn't write down what the exact load level was that Azure would be faster than Rackspace but it was much higher than the load we currently have.

Is there anything that can improve the database performance for the Azure platform? Any way to decrease latency on connections?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Are you hosting the database and web servers in the same data center?  how much slower is Azure than Rackspace?

Comment: This question belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow (it has nothing to do with programming). When you repost there, be sure to give more details. For instance: Are you running SQL Server in a VM, or are you using the SQL Database *service*?

Comment: Thanks David, I'm posting over at ServerFault.   Igorrek, I've had page loads go from 3 seconds on Rackspace to 9 seconds on Azure, not good. I don't know if they're in the same datacenter, not sure how to check.